# Python google cloud appengine requirements.txt load / python-files dont work anymore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, requirements.txt

my project used to push correctly without error in my Requirement.txt, but since 23-nov-2018 i can't push

> with endpoints or without, using gcloud app deploy

im sure it used to work since i track the version with git

```
Step #1: [0m[91mNo matching distribution found for python-files==0.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 135)) 
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

and when i delete python-files==0.0.4 from my Requirements it block on load==0.0.1 with the same error

and when i delete both of them i get this error since load is important

```
import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    from load import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'load'
[2018-11-27 16:09:53 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2018-11-27 16:09:53 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-11-27 16:09:53 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

what's the point here ! i dont find that logique

Comment: Can you share your entire `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Can you also share what you're using the `load` module for?

Comment: i had in main 
`from load import *`
unused but since it worked before i did look at the code 
i juste deleted the imporant`"from load import *"`  in my main and both of the load and python file from requirements.txt 
 and now it works, 
but i don't get why it worked before and not anymore
by the way thank you

Comment: Do you know why you added that import or what it was originally used for? Or did you take this code from an example somewhere?

Comment: @asli Can you post an answer with the solution for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 0):

[python-files](https://libraries.io/pypi/python-files)  librar  is not needed any more at least for me (python 3)

and for [load](https://libraries.io/pypi/python-files) there is a new version out [12/12/2018](https://pypi.org/project/load/)

For my probleme, all i did was to delete unsed code  `from load import *`